# A decade of Politics Stack Exchange – blog post input

Tags: discussion

Politics SE will be celebrating its 10-year anniversary this fall. We’ve been asked to supply a short text showcasing our site on the Stack Overflow blog. [This blog post celebrating last quarter’s anniversaries](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/27/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-spring-2022/) may be used as an example of the kind of texts we’re looking for.

We could highlight some hidden gem post(s), draw attention to a tag on the main site or perhaps you have another idea.

In this post, we’re soliciting suggestions on what to include in the paragraph representing Politics SE. Please try to be specific in your suggestion but remember that we can rewrite and combine multiple suggestions later on. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a deadline for when answers must be submitted by?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica yes I forgot to include that. We need to supply the final text to the CMs by October 20th. So if we get some suggestions over the coming weeks then we should have enough time to combine the top-voted suggestions into a nice paragraph.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of "Some reasons why a politics stackexchange might fail... and why it nevertheless worked." Kind of showing what an achievement this actually is on examples where one would not expect that level of ... call it maturity maybe.

Comment: @Trilarion something to that effect might work. Or maybe start with a focus on societal differences and then go back to Politics' attempt to bridge that gap? In that spirit, we could highlight a question where answers approach it through different ideologies and show how the diversity sometimes works as a strength.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be interesting to start by finding hidden gem posts, then write some story around the posts we want to highlight.

*'Hidden gems'* is a bit of a vague term, so far I've tried an approach that looks at questions in small tags with well-received questions. I haven't really gotten to the questions yet, but I wrote [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1651105) that retrieves tags using the follow criteria:

- The tag has between 4 and 10 questions which never made it on the HNQ.
- The tags are sorted in descending order of the average non-HNQ question score within that tag.

The idea is that these tags are rather niche because they have only a handful of questions associated with them. Sorting the tags by average question score is supposed to prioritize tags with good questions. HNQ questions are excluded from the SEDE query because those scores might give a distorted view numbers-wise.

So the next step is to go through some of these tags and find interesting questions or answers. I haven't really gotten to that yet but I welcome everyone who feels like it to join in and suggest posts (feel free to edit them in) based on this methodology (if you're using a completely different approach then it's probably better to just post a new answer).

#### Possibly interesting posts in niche tags worth highlighting

- [wikileaks](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikileaks): answer on international law and their force of law in the UK. Good references and extensive answer https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/27463

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a sentence such as

> Politics Stack Exchange can answer everything from [What are the powers of the British Monarch](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/what-governmental-power-does-the-monarch-hold-in-great-britain-in-practice) to [why doesn't the IRS make taxes simple?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30223/why-doesn-t-the-irs-just-send-me-a-bill-for-the-taxes-i-owe-based-on-the-info-th) However, Politics stack exchange isn't a place to promote political opinions; we try and keep the site unbiased and interesting for all.

I feel like there should probably be a few jokes added in, and maybe changed to have some better examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

> Politics is a place to get serious answers about political questions. We handle simple topics like [What is a Hung Parliament?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/what-is-a-hung-parliament), as well as highly contentious topics like [Why are so many Americans against Obamacare?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18620/why-are-so-many-americans-against-obamacare) Come exercise your Internet right to vote and explain in detail why that other party is wrong about...

I didn't pick that second question at random. It's [the top voted question on the site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes).

Comment: We have enough users coming to "explain in detail why that other party is wrong" and it is not a good thing or a desirable thing.